# How to access Jboss Manager/Admin portal

Tags: jboss

I am new to jboss, what is the url and configuration settings you need to have to access Jboss's Manager/Admin portal

Comment: probably `yourHost:8090/console/`, but it obviously depends on your configuration

Answer (score 3):

It depends on which version of jboss you are using.
for example, on JBOSS 5, you have to go to

```
http://localhost:8080/admin-console
```

Add the user at -JBOSS_HOME-\server\ -Server_Name-\conf\props\jmx-console-users.properties

On JBOSS version >= 6:

```
http://localhost:9990
```

Add management user with add-user.bat located in bin folder

Answer (score 1):

The url to access the JBoss Management Console is usually http://your_host:9990. Be careful that the console works only on localhost unless you edit your standalone.xml.
Before accessing the console you need to create a management user with the console script add-user.sh (or .bat) in your bin directory.
Hope this helps!
See this for more information: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Admin+Guide#AdminGuide-Accessingthewebconsole